# Making jQuery smoothly move

Tags: jquery, html

I am fading in an element using jQuery. Then I am fading another one that appears before the first one. When the second one is faded in it makes an unpleasant jolt.
[***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/4v3c73ye/4/)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hello").hide(0).delay(100).fadeIn(2000)
    $("#hi").hide(0).delay(2000).fadeIn(2000)
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>
<span id="hi">Hi There</span>  
<span id="hello"><strong>Hello</strong></span>
</h1>
```

I would like for the "*Hello*" to be faded into the same spot. Then when the "*Hi There*" fades in, the "*Hello*" will smoothly transition over instead of a jump. How would one go about doing this?

Comment: The problem is that `hide()` sets the `span`s' `display` attribute to `none`, meaning that they won't take up space. Fixing that is not easy...

Comment: @Shahar Hm. I guess I will just deal with the rough animation. Thanks a lot though for answering any way!

Comment: I have encountered a similar problem in the past but I don't recall what I did. The goal is to animate `visibility: visible` using jQuery, which I don't know how to do. Or just take a cheap way out.

Comment: As for CSS:visibility, it can be used.. But simply to do an instant. Otherwise you need to use opacity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to move the 'Hello' to the right and fade in the 'Hi' (rather than leave a blank space on the left of 'Hello'), you can try this:

HTML

```
<h1>
<div style = "position:relative">
<div style = "float:left" id="hi">Hi</div>  
<div style = "float:left" id="hello"> Hello</div>
</div>
</h1>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#hello").hide(0).delay(100).fadeIn(2000);
       $("#hi").css({opacity : 0, width : 0}).delay(5000).animate({'width' : '45px'},1000).animate({'opacity' : 1}, 1000);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4v3c73ye/7/)

Comment: Nice solution, I didn't think about using opacity. I tried to animate text color, and could make it work, but with the extra dependency of jqueryUI...

Comment: This does not resolve the original question, just shows another way to animate?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be:

1. Set the `position` of "hi" as `absolute` and the `position` of "hello" as `relative`.
2. Right after the `fadeIn` has started, calculate the width of the "hi" span.
3. Animate the "hello" span to a position that leaves just the space needed for the "hi" span.

You may want to set a non-breaking space (`&nbsp`) right after the text in the "hi" span so that the space is taken into account when calculating the width.

```
$("#hello, #hi").hide();
$("#hi").css("position", "absolute");
$("#hello").css("position", "relative");

// After 0.1 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#hello").fadeIn(2000);
}, 100);

// After 3 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#hi").fadeIn(2000);
    var hiWidth = $("#hi").width();
    $("#hello").animate({
        left : hiWidth + "px"
    }, 1000);
}, 3000);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/4v3c73ye/8/)**